# sublime text 2 html autocompletion in js/jsx files

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, reactjs, sublimetext2, emmet

I'd like to be able to autocomplete HTML tags inside `js`/`jsx` files within Sublime text 2. I have installed [Babel-sublime](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime) but HTML autocomplete isn't supported in it.

Any other options?

EDIT: Any good packages where HTML autocomplete works well within a `js` file? i.e. `Emmet` within a `js` file in Sublime text 2. Doesn't have to be `jsx`

Comment: Emmet works for every file, see https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#readme

Comment: Yes figured it out - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got `emmet` to work for `js/jsx` files in Sublime Text 2 by adding the following to my Key Bindings for the user `(Preferences -> Key Bindings - User)`

```
{
  "keys": ["tab"], 
  "command": "expand_abbreviation_by_tab", 
  // put comma-separated syntax selectors for which 
  // you want to expandEmmet abbreviations into "operand" key 
  // instead of SCOPE_SELECTOR.
  // Examples: source.js, text.html - source
  "context": [
{
  "operand": "source.js", 
  "operator": "equal", 
  "match_all": true, 
  "key": "selector"
}, 

// run only if there's no selected text
{
  "match_all": true, 
  "key": "selection_empty"
},

// don't work if completion popup is visible and you
// want to insert completion with Tab. If you want to
// expand Emmet with Tab even if popup is visible -- 
// remove this section
{
  "operand": false, 
  "operator": "equal", 
  "match_all": true, 
  "key": "auto_complete_visible"
}, 
{
  "match_all": true, 
  "key": "is_abbreviation"
}
```

]
    }
`